# ML.NET C# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ml.net

I get the following error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Could not determine an IDataView
> type and registrered custom types for member FillLevel
> Arg_ParamName_Name'

My code:

```
   public void CreateModel(IENumerable<MessageML> parData)
    {
        MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();
        IDataView testDateView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable<MessageML>(parData);
    }
```

MessageML class:

```
        public class MessageML
    {   
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

        public float? FillLevel { get; set; }

        public float? Temperature { get; set; }

        public float? Latitude { get; set; }

        public float? Longitude { get; set; }

        public float Unit { get; set; }
        
    }
```

The query to get parData:

```
    public IEnumerable<MessageML> GetAllMessagesByUnit(int parUnitId)
    {
        var tempQuery = from m in context.Message
                        where m.Unit == 1
                        select new MessageML
                        {
                            DateTime = m.DateTime,
                            FillLevel = (float?)m.FillLevel,
                            Temperature = (float?)m.Temperature,
                            Latitude = (float?)m.Latitude,
                            Longitude = (float?)m.Longitude,
                            Unit = (float)m.Unit,
                        };

        return  tempQuery.ToList();

    }
```

Comment: You are using entity where there is a mapping between the c# classes and the database tables/field.  The mapping for variable FillLevel is failing.  When you modify the database you  must refresh the mapping so the classes and database match.  FillLevel is a float and accepts null values.

Comment: I use entity indeed, and  the database and classes are matching, but messageML is not part of my database but just a class that I use for creating a model

Comment: The method LoadFromEnumerable() is looking for a mapping which doesn't exist.

Comment: @JJNL77 Did you find any solution? Regarding your question, are you sure that `tempQuery` has any items on it?